# managing and controlling the post back priority

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, postback

I have a web page which is contained a Data Filter and a report.The Data Filter is a user control. The report is loaded inside the main page so totally i have two pages. one user control and one web page.
Now i am going to gather the data by clicking a button inside the user control then i can use it to filter the table, but it seems that during the post back it goes first to the Page_Load method of the main, not the user control so the report is constructed before filtering.The BtnPreviewReport_Click must be executed earlier than the page_Load. 
What should i do ?

User control

```
   protected void BtnPreviewReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Date = Year.Text + "/" + Month.Text + "/" + Day.Text;          

        }
```

Main Page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string date = UserControls1.Date;
                Response.Write(date);
        }
```

**Output :  Nothing**

Comment: Are you familiar with how events are fired in a web page..? also create a `Pre_Init` method in the page load event do some `if(IsPostBack){ }else{ }` structure.. you may also want to declare the `Date` variable as static.. could you edit your question and show the user control class and the data type of `Date` it's hard to tell what you are or are not doing based on what you have posted because one cannot determine when and how you initialized the user control..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the ButtonClick event should be run earlier than page load.
But here's a simple way to solve your question:

```
private bool isPageLoaded = false;
private bool isButtonClicked = false;


private void ButtonClick()
{
    isButtonClicked = true;
    doTheFirstThing();
    if( isPageLoaded )
    {
        doTheSecondThing();
    }
}

private void PageLoad()
{
    isPageLoaded = true;
    if( isButtonClicked )
    {
        doTheSecondThing();
    }
    // else let the button click handle the SecondThing()
}
```